# single apache with many virtualhosts but only some of them have https

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache-2.4, https

I have apache listening on 80 and runs 4 sites:

- aaa.com:80
- bbb.com:80
- ccc.com:80
- ddd.com:80

I enable port 443 and add SSL cert only for the first 2 sites ("aaa" and "bbb") and it works well, so now my virtualhosts are like:

- aaa.com:80
- aaa.com:443
- bbb.com:80
- bbb.com:443
- ccc.com:80
- ddd.com:80

The problem is that a user who will try accessing the https version of "ccc" or "ddd" will get to the VirtualHost of "aaa" which acts as the default 443 host since it's the first one defined for 443.

How do you generally solve this problem assuming that:

- I cannot obtain SSL certs for the remaining "ccc" and "ddd" sites
- I cannot move those "ccc" and "ddd" to another server (which would only listen to 80)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a redirect from https to http on the  virtualhosts not using a certificate? I have the same setup as you, but I have to check my notes how I did it.

Comment: I don't think this is doable. Having a VirtualHost on 443 without certificates gives me: `Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured`.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a second IP address for that server and then configure apache to listen on

- port 80 of the first IP address for sites without SSL
- ports 80 and 443 of the second IP address for sites with SSL

Then set the DNS records of your sites accordingly.